# jQuery onclick delete row from mysql table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql-delete

I wrote a function to delete an item from cart; the success message flash, but the item is not getting deleted.  There's no error message being flagged in the console. However I think my query is wrong.

**cart.php**

```
         <form id='updateCartForm' action="update_cart.php" method="get">
 <input name="cart_item_id" type = "hidden"  id ="cart_item_id" value='<?=$product['id'];?>'>
 </form>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick='update_cart(); return false;'>&times</button>
```

**footer.php**

```
function update_cart(){
    jQuery('#updateCartErrors').html("");
    var cart_item_id = jQuery('#cart_item_id').val();
    var error = ' ';
var data = jQuery('#updateCartForm').serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
    url : '/ecommerce/customer/parsers/update_cart.php ',
    method: 'get',
    data :  data, 
    success : function (){
        location.reload();
    },
    error : function(){alert("Something went wrong");}
});
}
```

**update_cart.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ecommerce/core/init.php'; 

$cart_item_id = $_GET['cart_item_id'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM cart WHERE id = $cart_item_id" ;


//flash success message
$domain =($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost')?'.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']:false;
$_SESSION['success_flash'] = $product['prod_name']. ' was deleted from your cart.';
```

Comment: @e4c5: yes `$product['id']` is being generated by another query to display products from cart.

Comment: did you check if that form is rendered correctly but inspecting the html

Comment: How many of these `<form id='updateCartForm'..` do you have in the page? Is it possible you have multiple `id ="cart_item_id"` in the page?

Comment: @Sean:  I have only one form on the page. But if that can help actually the `$_SESSION['success_flash'] = $product['prod_name']. ' was deleted from your cart.';  ` flashes the wrong name of the product, it flashes first product on cart. So say I have a `t-shirt`, a `hat` and a `ring` on the cart, whether I delete the hat or the ring, success_flash `t-shirt was deleted from cart`

Comment: Your flash is wrong just because you are selecting the first/one row from you cart, not the row you deleted.

Comment: you haven't executed your query

Comment: @NewbeeDev: yes im getting super tired thanks,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update code as given below and try :

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM cart WHERE id =" . $cart_item_id;   // update this
$db->query($sql); //add this new line in code.
```

If any confusion please let me ask.
Thanks...

Comment: from the docs - [*When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables are parsed within it*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). so your query is equivalent to the OPs.

Comment: if you are going to suggest a change the to query, the suggestion should have been to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

I think you need to append value instead.

```
      $sql = "DELETE FROM cart WHERE id =".$cart_item_id;
```

Comment: from the docs - [*When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables are parsed within it*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). so your query is equivalent to the OPs.

Comment: if you are going to suggest a change the to query, the suggestion should have been to use prepared statements